# Extract data table from text file Java

Tags: java, extract

I have a problem of extracting table of data from text file using java.

The table is arrange as below:

```
FirstName Surname Mark Age Height

Charlie   Brown   5         170cm
Lucy      Harlow      16    160cm
Jame      Horde   11  18
Charrlot  White       19    165cm
Jimmy     Lutton  15  17    180cm
```

I intended to have a person class which has appropriate variables to stored data such as first name, surname, mark and age.

However when I tried to extract the line by line to get the data line and use `string.split()` to break down the string to get the column. Then I cannot determine the which data belong to which column.

```
line = br.readLine()
```

will return "Charlie   Brown   5         170cm"

and `value = line.split("//s+");` will return `value[Charlie,Brown,5,170cm]`. At this point I cannot determine which value is belong to which column.

Please help

Comment: So, in first data row it is 5\t\t170cm?

Comment: yes but if i run the loop then it is difficult to determine which data belong to which row...

Answer (score 0):

After you extract the line, for each line You can find the index of `\t` using `indexOf` method and then use `subString` to extract part.

Comment: or should just use the loop to check every single leter

Comment: yes, some conditions need to be checked, like empty line, empty string, string when expected int .. etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you file is tab separated then you should just split on the tab characters instead of 1 or more white-space characters.

```
value = line.split("\t");
```

This will put the strings in the correct rows and empty strings if there is nothing there.